build data dynamic for data in dataset for chartjs in javascript
I would like to make the data been made dynamic according the variable 'AmountOfPoints'
Now i'm working with a switch and make the data fixed (please see example below):
__processPlot1() {
  if (this.__Plot1 !== null) {
    //Check how many points are used for draw the camtable
    let AmountOfPoints = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (this.__Plot1[i].Used === true) {
        AmountOfPoints++;
      }
    }
    //console.log("AmountOfPoints: " + AmountOfPoints);

    switch (AmountOfPoints) {
      case 10:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[4].X, y: this.__Plot1[4].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[5].X, y: this.__Plot1[5].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[6].X, y: this.__Plot1[6].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[7].X, y: this.__Plot1[7].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[8].X, y: this.__Plot1[8].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[9].X, y: this.__Plot1[9].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;

      case 9:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[4].X, y: this.__Plot1[4].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[5].X, y: this.__Plot1[5].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[6].X, y: this.__Plot1[6].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[7].X, y: this.__Plot1[7].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[8].X, y: this.__Plot1[8].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;

      case 8:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[4].X, y: this.__Plot1[4].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[5].X, y: this.__Plot1[5].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[6].X, y: this.__Plot1[6].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[7].X, y: this.__Plot1[7].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;

      case 7:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[4].X, y: this.__Plot1[4].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[5].X, y: this.__Plot1[5].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[6].X, y: this.__Plot1[6].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;

      case 6:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[4].X, y: this.__Plot1[4].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[5].X, y: this.__Plot1[5].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;

      case 5:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[4].X, y: this.__Plot1[4].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;

      case 4:
        this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
          data: [
            { x: this.__Plot1[0].X, y: this.__Plot1[0].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[1].X, y: this.__Plot1[1].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[2].X, y: this.__Plot1[2].Y },
            { x: this.__Plot1[3].X, y: this.__Plot1[3].Y },
          ],
          fill: false,
          showLine: true,
          tension: 0,
          borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
          pointRadius: 7,
        };
        break;
    }
  }
  this.__Plot.update();
}

This is working, but i would like to have it be dynamic, if for example i would have 50 points, i don't need to add them all manually like in my example above, thank you

This is an example how the array looks like
Plot1 is receiving the data from that array (it has valid data)
Update: the result of the requested console.log:


You mean something like


// test data
const Plot1 = [
  {"Used":true, "X":1,"Y":10},
  {"Used":true, "X":2,"Y":20},
  {"Used":false,"X":3,"Y":30}, // will be skipped
  {"Used":true, "X":4,"Y":40}
];


    const plots = Plot1; // this.__Plot1; // change back to this.Plot1
    const data = plots
      .filter(({Used}) => Used)
      .map(({X, Y}) => ({x:X, y:Y}));

    console.log(data)
    /* Uncomment when happy
    this.__Plot.data.datasets[0] = {
      data: data,
      fill: false,
      showLine: true,
      tension: 0,
      borderColor: "#CD5C5C",
      pointRadius: 7
    };*/




thank you, i'm getting an error  at the { }    on the const data

I used lowercase x,y, your data has upper case. try my updated code

Still the same mate.  On the first { at Used(at filter), i get:  Expected identifier and on the } at Used(at filter) i get:  Expected ')'

Can you post an example of a Plot1 with 3 or so plots in your question? If it does not look like my testdata then that is the explanation

I did not mean how your database looks like. I wanted a console.log(this.__Plot1)
